# Updating AWS Lambda function while another app is using it

Tags: aws-lambda

This is not code-specific, rather a flow/process question.

Say I have a lambda function that's being used by another aws process. Data is flowing through and being processed.

All of a sudden I notice a bug or I want to add some additional code, but I don't want to have any data loss from the existing process. What is the correct process to update the lambda function? I feel like I should be able to do it with aliasing and versioning, but I'm not sure what the correct practice is.

so basically:

create lambda function and hook it to another process => oh no some bugs exist! => update code => now I want to hook the process to new lambda function without breaking/stopping the old one (to make sure all data is processed and lambda function is stopped)

Is there a way to graceful this?

Comment: I can't find a source on this now, but I think lambda does not terminate any running requests when you deploy a new one. Any running processes will run till end and new ones will be directed to the new version.

Comment: So I should be able to go create new version (take a snapshot)=> update the code or do I even need a new version in this case?

Comment: in https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/
it says `When you update a Lambda function, there will be a brief window of time, typically less than a minute, when requests could be served by either the old or the new version of your function.`

Comment: Just update the function. The running process won't be affected.

Comment: You can easily test that by yourself by creating a function which sleeps for 1 or 2 minutes, then trigger the function and in this period of time you'll update your code and trigger the function again => the first function should continue to run after the sleep and a second execution with the new code should be running as well.

Comment: @s.hesse the issue is we don't know how long we need to wait right?

Comment: @JChao Yeah. From my experience the new code is used almost instantly, but there is no guarantee for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage aliases and function versioning that Lambda provides.

Here is a flow that I use in my deployments

> Dev Alias that points to $LATEST
>
> Prod Alias that points to a version that I've published.

When I'm ready to update the Published version to the new version I've been developing I use [Traffic Shifting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-traffic-shifting-using-aliases.html) to send a percentage of traffic to the new version while running the old version.

In your case you can use redirect all new traffic to the new version in one go after you are ready to publish.

AWS also has a good guide here on how to do safe deployments for Lambda functions with CodeDeploy -> https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/implementing-safe-aws-lambda-deployments-with-aws-codedeploy/